# How can I get a coloumn with mah operations in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am preparing a database in MYSQL about cars Kilometers.
I have three coloumns in MYSQL database: Kilometers1, Kilometers2, Total.
There are some value in coloumns Kilometers1 (ex. 1000km) and Kilometers2 (ex. 2000km). How can I get the total Kilometers in Total coloumn (so 3000km) in MYSQL?

thanks

Comment: : Kilometers1 + Kilometers2 checking for nulls in an update statement https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Comment: You might also look at generated columns- but I would be careful about storing derived data

Answer (score 1):

Just like this

```
UPDATE mileage SET Total = Kilometers1 + Kilometers2
```

Comment: Ok but this is a query that I have to do everytime. Is there something that automatically calculate the total in MYSQL?

Comment: Well, you can do it in 3 different ways - (a) provide the total at the moment of insert, (b) calculate the total at the moment of select, (c) use a trigger which fires on insert and update and which automatically sets the total